# Android: how to get the default date format based on device timezone

Tags: java, android, datetime, timezone

### Is there any simple way to fetch the default date format as per user's timezone?

The `SimpleDateFormat()` gives the date format as per the user locale. I'm in search of a scenario where I need to convert a supplied Date into timezone based date format.

Say e.g., A user set her locale as 'Chinese' and in German timezone should result in the date format as `dd.mm.yyyy`

Comment: Your question doesn’t really make sense. A time zone has a set of historic and known future offsets from UTC, but it does not have a default date format. If the user sets the time zone to Europe/Berlin, you may be able to figure out that some format for Germany would be appropriate. Some countries have more languages and a date format for each language. And if the user sets the time zone to +02:00 (which is stupid, but some users do), there certainly doesn’t come any date format with it.

Comment: Any suggestion where the req is to convert date to default timezone based format?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as follows:

1. Use a [Geolocation API](https://ip-api.com/docs/) to get the country code e.g by parsing the JSON from the URL, http://ip-api.com/json you can get the country code.
2. Loop through `Locale.getAvailableLocales()`, let's say using the loop variable, `locale` and return the `locale` for which `locale.getCountryCode().equals(the-country-code-obtained-from-the-json)`
3. With the obtained `Locale`, get the date pattern as shown below:

   ```
   String datePattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.SHORT, null,
                       IsoChronology.INSTANCE, locale);
   ```

Comment: Arvind, thanks again. 
Can we think of alternate solution while date formatting w.r.t. timezone?

Comment: @Faisal - A format (e.g. date format, time format, date & time format, number format etc.) is part of `Locale`. A time-zone doesn't have anything to do with `Locale`. There are many countries (e.g. the USA, Russia etc.) which have many time-zones but a single `Locale` i.e. irrespective of which time-zone of the USA the user is in, the Locale (and hence formats) will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to fetch dateformat from device:

```
Format dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
String pattern = ((SimpleDateFormat) dateFormat).toLocalizedPattern();
```

Comment: Thanks, but above snippet results in date format as per locale.