# Will this give me the correct local time of the user?

Tags: java, datetime, time, dayofweek, localtime

I need to figure out a way to get the user's local time reliably. After researching, one potential solution could be:

Day of the week in user's location:

```
int dayOfWeek = ZonedDateTime.now(Clock.systemDefaultZone()).getDayOfWeek().ordinal();
```

Actual time in the user's location:

```
LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemDefaultZone()));
```

Is this all correct? Am I correct to be using `Clock.systemDefaultZone()`? If so, I wonder how `Clock.systemDefaultZone()` is able to magically figure out the correct time zone?

Comment: You wrote in your question: _I wonder how `Clock.systemDefaultZone()` is able to magically figure out the correct time zone?_ Did you try looking at the source code of method `systemDefaultZone()` in class `Clock`?

Comment: Do you have any special requirements for how the days of the week are numbered? Usually one should not use `ordninal()` but either `getValue()` (for ISO days from 1 = Monday through 7 = Sunday) or a well-chosen `WeekFields` object for some other numbering.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your first example, you don't need a `ZonedDateTime`, a `LocalDate` would do since you only care about the day in the week, not the time in that day. Also note that `LocalDate.now()` uses the system default clock and you don't need to explicitly specifly it.

Regarding that default clock, `Clock.systemDefaultZone()` is based on the system default time zone, which is retrieved by querying [`TimeZone.getDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--):

> Gets the default TimeZone of the Java virtual machine. If the cached default TimeZone is available, its clone is returned. Otherwise, the method takes the following steps to determine the default time zone.
>
> - Use the user.timezone property value as the default time zone ID if it's available.
> - Detect the platform time zone ID. The source of the platform time zone and ID mapping may vary with implementation.
> - Use GMT as the last resort if the given or detected time zone ID is unknown.
>   The default TimeZone created from the ID is cached, and its clone is returned. The user.timezone property value is set to the ID upon return.

Comment: Is Clock.systemDefaultZone() called internally within LocalDate? When would one use ZonedDateTime?

Comment: See my edit. Use ZonedDateTime if you need a time in a specific timezone. In your case you only need the date.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as this:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Local date
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println(today);

        // Local time
        LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
        System.out.println(now);

        // Local date and time
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // Day of week
        DayOfWeek dayOfWeek = today.getDayOfWeek();
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek);
        System.out.println(dayOfWeek.getValue());
    }
}
```

**Output for my time-zone:**

```
2020-10-03
17:47:57.426833
2020-10-03T17:47:57.426943
SATURDAY
6
```

Comment: Is `Clock.systemDefaultZone()` called internally within `LocalDateTime`. When would one use `ZonedDateTime`?

Comment: No...[`LocalDateTime#now`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now--) uses the time-zone of the JVM on which you execute it...it's equivalent to `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())`. Whenever you need to deal with date-time in a time-zone different from the JVM's time-zone, you need to work with ZonedDateTime. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Comment: I actually want the code to work for any user that the service is getting the request from (i.e. the time should be GB local time if the user is in GB, US EST if the user is in east coast). Will simple LocalDateTime work?

Comment: @no_clue_so - Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63793425/android-how-to-get-the-default-date-format-based-on-device-timezone/63799256#63799256

Comment: @no_clue_so - I hope the solution worked for you. Do not forget to mark the answer as accepted so that future visitors can also use the solution confidently.